# Cambiar el formato de fecha en un jdata chooser

Tags: java

quisiera saber si me ayudan, tengo un data chooser  combo en netbeans y quiero cambiar el formato a yyyy-MM-dd porque por default unicamnete tiene el formato dd-MM-yy. estoy trabajando en netbeans 8.2... le agradeceria bastante su colaboracion.
estaba buscando el datFormatString en las propiedades pero no hay.

Answer (score 0):

usa el atributo `jChooder.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");`